# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_root'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am completely new to Python 3, just following simple exercises from YouTube.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nefopNkZmB4&index=3&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGAcbMi1sH6oAMk4JHw91mC_

This is my code:

```
    from tkinter import *


def iCalc(source, side):
    storeObj = Frame(source, borderwidth=4, bd=4, bg="powder blue")
    storeObj.pack(side=side, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
    return storeObj


def button(source, side, text, command=None):
    storeObj = Button(source, text=text, command=command)
    storeObj.pack(side=side, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
    return storeObj


class app(Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.option_add('*Font', 'arial 20 bold')
        self.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
        self.master.title('Calculator')

    display = StringVar()
    Entry(self, relief=RIDGE, textvariable=display, justify='right', bd=30, bg="powder blue").pack(side=TOP, expand=YES,
                                                                                                   fill=BOTH)
for clearBut in (["CE"], ["C"]):
    erase = iCalc(self, TOP)
for ichar in clearBut:
    button(erase, LEFT, ichar,
           lambda storeObj=display, q=ichar: storeObj.set(''))

for NumBut in ("789/", "456*", "123-", "0.+"):
    FunctionNum = iCalc(self, TOP)
for iEquals in NumBut:
    button(FunctionNum, LEFT, iEquals,
           lambda storeObj=display, q=iEquals: storeObj.set(storeObj.get() + q))
EqualsButton = iCalc(self, TOP)
for iEquals in '=':
    if iEquals in "=":
        btniEquals = button(EqualsButton, LEFT, iEquals)
        btniEquals.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>',
                        lambda e, s=self, storeObj=display: s.calc(storeObj), '+')
else:
    btniEquals = button(EqualsButton, LEFT, iEquals,
                        lambda storeObj=display, s=' %s ' % iEquals: storeObj.set(storeObj.get() + s))


def calc(self, display):
    try:
        display.set(eval(display.get()))
    except:
        display.set("ERROR")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app().mainloop()
```

I am getting error:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You cannot create any more widgets after exiting the main loop. Remove the last two statements of your program .

Comment: I am sorry, but which last two statements?  
  `#Entry(self,relief = RIDGE,
          #textvariable = display,justify = 'right', bd = 30, bg = "powder blue").pack(side = TOP, expand = YES, fill = BOTH)`

Comment: `display=...` and `Entry(self,...` That's the last two.

Comment: #DYZ i took those lines off, but the error still remains.I also updated my complete code. 
Thank you

Comment: Please fix your code formatting. After the change, it is not clear what your code is doing now at all.

Comment: I think I fixed. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Because of the indentation, `display = StringVar()` is not in a method. That means it is getting executed when the class is first defined. You cannot create an instance of `StringVar` until after the root window has been created.

You need to add one more level of indentation for that line, and the line below it.

Comment: I work in SQL, and it doesnt matter how you put your code, unless you want to make it look pretty.  So in python I always have to be measure the distance between the lines? Or how should I call it?