# Return the value by OptionMenu

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to return the value by function option_changed and store it outside a function
I have tried using global variable but it is not working
I am using **python 3.7.3** and **Tkinter GUI**

```
def option_changed(*args):
    global en
    en=format(variable.get())
    print(format(variable.get()))
    #return format(variable.get())
    print("Inside fun"+en)
# making data frame
data1 = pd.read_csv("ver.csv")
print("data", data1.columns)
variable = StringVar(root)
variable.set("-select-") # default value
variable.trace("w", option_changed) # trace value
w = OptionMenu(root, variable, *data1.columns).pack()
#print(en)
mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `return` function

```
def option_changed(*args):
    en=format(variable.get())
    print(format(variable.get()))
    #return format(variable.get())
    print("Inside fun"+en)
    return en #<--- With this you return the variable
# making data frame
output_variable = option_changed() #<--- With this line you save the output of the option_changed() method into the variable en
data1 = pd.read_csv("ver.csv")
print("data", data1.columns)
variable = StringVar(root)
variable.set("-select-") # default value
variable.trace("w", option_changed()) # trace value #<--- What you probably wanted was this, you were missing the paranthese here.
w = OptionMenu(root, variable, *data1.columns).pack()
print(output_variable) #<--- Now you can use this variable 
mainloop()
```

Comment: not working it is giving error :- return self.func(*args)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: @AmanMisri Can you give me the whole error message so I can see which line is at fault? And can you show me how the code looks now

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\scraping\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: @AmanMisri StringVar() can only be executed after the root Window has been created. For more info take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42081609/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-root)

Comment: I am exceuting Stringvar() after root window

Comment: @AmanMisri Then this problem probably doesn't concern this question anymore