# why does tkinter root in Python need to be created first?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have searched stackoverflow and found various answers, but can't figure out the why.  Hoping someone can help or simply point me to somewhere that I could read about the following tkinter issue (self taught, trying to learn tkinter).

I try to follow the approach set forth in "A Simple Hello World Program" at https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html.  And it works and all is good.  But I'm experimenting to get to a bare minimum to understand things better and have what I believe to be a chicken and egg conundrum.

This code works just fine to give me a window:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.mainloop()
```

Code noted below works if I put the code above "root =" and does not if below "root =".

```
var = StringVar()
label = tk.Label(root, textvariable=var, relief=RAISED)
var.set("Hey!? How are you doing?")
label.pack()
```

I get an error stating "'NoneType' object has no attribute '_root'".  I understand it is because root has yet to be defined.

I think Brian Oakley superbly answered my question at [AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_root'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42081609/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-root)
He wrote: "You cannot create an instance of StringVar until after the root window has been created."

What I'm wondering is why is that the case?  I want to understand why as I think it will make me a better programmer. And I've looked and can't put my finger on the why.

Comment: "Code noted below works if I put the code above "root =" and does not if below "root ="." Is that supposed to be the other way around? `tk` implementation details aside, `tk.Label(root, ...)` raises a `NameError` if you haven't actually defined the variable `root` yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why does tkinter root in Python need to be created first?

Tkinter is a wrapper around an embedded tcl/tk interpreter. Every tkinter object represents an object in this embedded interpreter. The interpreter isn't initialized until you create the root window. It is impossible to create a tkinter object which exists in this interpreter until the interpreter exists, so you must create the root window before creating any tkinter objects.

Also, widgets exist in a tree like hierarchy. By definition a tree requires a root. It is literally impossible to create any widget (except the root window itself) without an existing root window. If you create a widget without creating a root window, one will be created for you. That does not happen, however, when you create one of the special Tkinter variables (`StringVar`, etc).

Comment: I know you advocate an OOP and have indicated you preferred approach https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466561/best-way-to-structure-a-tkinter-application

Comment: I know you advocate an OOP and have indicated you preferred approach https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466561/best-way-to-structure-a-tkinter-application. And in that post your highest level class was tk.Frame.  But why not have the first class be the root window and have everything inherit from that top level class?

Comment: @wiseass: inheritance isn't for sharing data. There should never be more than one root window, so inheriting from such a class wouldn't make any sense. I don't see what that has to do with this answer, though.